# Eclipse maven plugin, can't update index

Tags: java, maven

In Eclipse m2 maven plugin, I always get this error in console,

```
4/29/11 2:24:29 PM EDT: Updating index ibiblio.net|http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository
4/29/11 2:24:45 PM EDT: Unable to update index for ibiblio.net|http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository
```

do you know what is the reason ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you read the message there? http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository/

Comment: It's helpful to actually include a short snippet of outside links in the answer directly.

Comment: what should I change ? currently my setting is like this <mirror>
  <id>ibiblio.net</id> 
  <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository</url> 
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
 </mirror>